# Find matches in a log file based on the time and ID

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a radius log file which is comma separated.

```
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","Stop","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC400",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","ATGGSN17","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","Start","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC500",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","A","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
```

Is it possible through any Linux command line tool like awk to count the number of occurrences where the second column (the time) and the seventh column (the number) are the same, and a `Start` event follows a `Stop` event?

I want to find the occurrences where a `Stop` is followed by a `Start` at the same time for the same number.

There will be other entries as well with the same timestamp between these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say very clearly what kind of result you want, but you should use Perl with [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) to process CSV files.

This program just prints the three relevant fields from all lines of the file where the event is `Start` or `Stop` and the time and the ID string are duplicated.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

open my $fh, '<', 'text.csv' or die $!;

my %data;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  my ($time, $event, $id) = @$row[1,3,6];
  next unless $event eq 'Start' or $event eq 'Stop';
  push @{ $data{"$time/$id"} }, $row;
}

for my $lines (values %data) {
  next unless @$lines > 1;
  print "@{$_}[1,3,6]\n" for @$lines;
  print "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
00:52:23 Stop 15444111111
00:52:23 Start 15444111111
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "stop" line is followed immediately by the "start" line, you could try the following:

```
awk -f cnt.awk input.txt
```

where `cnt.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

$4=="\"Stop\"" {
    key=($2 $5)
    startl=$0
    getline
    if ($4=="\"Start\"") {
        if (key==($2 $5)) {
           print startl
           print $0
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

If there can be other lines between a "Start" and "Stop" line, you could try:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
$4=="\"Stop\"" {
    a[($2 $5)]=$0
    next
}

$4=="\"Start\"" {
    key=($2 $5)
    if (key in a) {
        sl[++i]=a[key]
        el[i]=$0
    }
}

END {
    nn=i
    for (i=1; i<=nn; i++) {
        print sl[i]
        print el[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the stop line is not always followed by a start against a particular number for such cases

Comment: Ok. Can there be other "Stop" lines between a given matching "Stop" and "Start"?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following using GNU sed & awk

```
sed -n '/Stop/,/Start/{/Stop/{h};/Start/{H;x;p}}' text.csv \
| awk -F, 'NR%2 != 0 {prev=$0;time=$2;num=$7}  \
           NR%2 == 0 {if($2==time && $7==num){print prev,"\n", $0}}'
```

The sed part would select pairing **Stop** line and **Start** line. There can(or not) be other lines between the two lines, and if there are multiple **Stop** lines before a **Start** line the last **Stop** line would be selected (This may be not necessary in this case...).

The awk part would compare the selected pairs in sed part, if the second and seventh columns are identical, the pair would be print out.

My test as below:

text.csv:

```
"1/3/2013","00:52:20","NASK","Stop","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC400",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","ATGGSN17","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","XXXX","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC400",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","ATGGSN17","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","Stop","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC400",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","ATGGSN17","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","XXXX","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC400",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","ATGGSN17","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","Start","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC500",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","A","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
"1/3/2013","00:52:28","NASK","Stop","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC400",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","ATGGSN17","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
"1/3/2013","00:52:29","NASK","Start","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC500",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","A","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
```

The output:

```
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","Stop","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC400",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","ATGGSN17","2","7",,,"1385772885",, 
"1/3/2013","00:52:23","NASK","Start","15444111111","200","15444111111","15444111111","10.142.98.190","moen",,,,,"D89BA1F93E5DC500",,,"31026","216.155.166.8","310260010265999",,"10.184.81.145","780246","18","A","2","7",,,"1385772885",,
```